# How to change an array into a html table in sample way?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have a dynamic array :

```
Array
(
    [user1] => Array
        (
            [012014] => 6788
            [022014] => 11141
            [032014] => 6143
            [042014] => 936
            [052014] => 936
        )

    [user2] => Array
        (
            [012014] => 9
            [022014] => 25
            [032014] => 37
            [042014] => 17
            [052014] => 16
        )

)
```

And I want to display it like this :

```
Users |              Months
      |---------------------------------
      |012014|022014|032014|042014|052014
------------------------------------------
user1 | 6788 | 11141| 6143 |  936 |  936
-------------------------------------------
user2 |   9  |   25 |   37 |   17 |  16
```

I can't seem to work it out! Here's what I've been trying :

```
echo "<table>";

foreach($month_all as $site=>$value){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>$site</td>";
   foreach ($value as $column) {
      echo "<td>$column</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}    
echo "</table>";
```

Any way I can do it in a clean way ?

Comment: You need 2 `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two loops: one for displaying all the key values. One for displaying all the values of the users. This version uses `<th>` to handle the table headers and takes care of the indentation properly because it's using the alternative `foreach` style.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th colspan="5">Months</th>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <?php foreach ($month_all['user1'] as $key): ?>
                <td><?= $key ?></td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($month_all as $site => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $site ?></td>
            <?php foreach ($value as $column): ?>
                <td><?= $column ?></td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?> 
</table>
```

[**Live demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4t10YZ)

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <?php
        foreach($Arr['user1'] as $key1=>$th)
        {
            ?>
            <th><?=$key1?></th>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($Arr as $row)
{ ?>
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach($row as $column){
        ?>
        <td><?=$column?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give u the exact table as in your question

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "user1" => array(
        "012014" => 6788,
        "022014" => 11141,
        "032014" => 6143,
        "042014" => 936,
        "052014" => 936
    ) ,

    "user2" => array(
        "012014" => 9,
        "022014" => 25,
        "032014" => 37,
        "042014" => 17,
        "052014" => 16
    )
);

print '<table border="1px solid black"><tr><td>Users</td><td colspan="5" style="text-align: center">Month</td></tr>';
print '<tr><td></td>';
foreach (reset($array) as $key => $value) {
    print '<td>' . $key . '</td>';
}
print '</tr>';
foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>' . $key . '</td>';
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        print '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
    print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
?>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clearly speaking using implode is not a good method to use.But i wanted to give you an idea that you should use `colspan='.count(array_keys($month_all['user1'])).'` in header to get month over all columns.

```
echo '<table><tr><td rowspan=2>Users</td><td colspan='.count(array_keys($month_all['user1'])).'>Months</td></tr>';
echo '<td>'.rtrim(implode(array_keys($month_all['user1']),'</td><td>'),'<td>').'';
foreach($month_all as $site=>$value){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>$site</td>";
   foreach ($value as $column) {
      echo "<td>$column</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
```